# Android application removed from Play Store, but users still have active subscriptions.

Tags: android, subscription, billing

Android application removed from Play Store, but users still have active subscriptions.

It is wrong that after some time my application will charge money from subscribers, but actually my application is removed from Play Store.

I removed my application because supporting server became too expensive. so I removed the app.

Most of subscribers from United Arab Emirates and they bought most expensive subscriptions instead of cheaper ones.

I didn't find any solution to stop charge money from subscribers.

Comment: change your code buddy!. stop it from there.

Comment: @ZaidMirza I don't understand. what I need to do? a lot of people don't understand, that app is removed. they are too rich to spot that app is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove subscription of user do this things
 
1. Go to **Play Console** 
2. Open **Order Management** page 
3. Find an **order id** of user that subscribed

then open this order and unsubscribe user.